# How to calculate number of different combinations along a line?

Tags: combinations

If I have a straight line consisting of *n* points, and I have to get from the first to the last point, using any combination of "hops" along points, how do I calculate how many possible combinations there are?

Example: a line with points A, B, C. I can either go from A -> C, or A -> B -> C. That's two possible combinations.

Comment: Can the hops be of any length? And do they all have to be "forward"?

Comment: Yes, to both. As long as it takes you from start to finish, forward only.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the hops can be of arbitrary length and each hop must go forward:

Pick any subset of the $n-2$ points in the middle. Then hop from the first point to each of the points in that subset in order, and then to the last point. Each subset of the $n-2$ points in the middle yields a unique combination of hops, so we have $2^{n-2}$ combinations of hops.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a name or terminology for this kind of combination-finding? I need to write it in a computer scripting language, to list all possible combinations of hops from start to finish.

Comment: You are looking for [compositions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28combinatorics%29) (The parameter is different by $1$.)